# Animação Gradiente CSS

Tags: html5, css3, css-animations

Estou tentando fazer uma animação igual ao deste link: https://codepen.io/TheCodeDepository/pen/jKBaoN

**Acontece que, o código abaixo (o qual eu copiei linha por linha) está com algum problema que não permite a animação iniciar:**

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    animation: mygradient 2s ease infinite;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes mygradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Meu código</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```

**Já o código abaixo (copiado do link informado inicialmente) funciona perfeitamente.**
*(OBS: eu removi algumas linhas do código original por achá-las desnecessárias. Tanto é que o código funciona sem elas).*

```css
section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Código Original</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```

Como já estou há horas comparando meu código que não funciona com o que funciona e tentando entender o que há de errado, mas sem resultado, decidi por pedir auxílio à alguém que possa me ajudar. Fico grato desde já por alguma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc usou apenas o *shorthand* do `background` para o gradiente, e deveria ser `background-image`

Repare que onde estava

```
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
```

Agora está

```
background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
```

Quando vc usa o *shorthand* depois (abaixo) de algum outro atributo de  `background`, como no caso do `background-size`, ele acaba ficando com o valor padrão que é 100%, ai o efeito não funciona, pois o `background-size` deveria ser 400%

**OBS:** Se vc inverter a ordem e usar primeiro o *shorthand* `background: gradiente` e abaixo dele o `background-size` **tb da certo**, pelo mesmo motivo explicado acima!

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    animation: mygradient 2s ease infinite;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes mygradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Meu código</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Não fazia ideia de que a ordem dos atributos nesse contexto fosse influenciar de tal forma resultado do código.

Comment: @RicardoPassos esse é um caso bem particular, pois vc usou a propriedade no formato shorthand `background`, depois da propriedade objetiva `background-size, ai o shorthand "zerou" a outra  propriedade...

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente, não sei o que ocorre que seu código não funciona. Mas, copiei o código "que funciona" que você postou e substitui as cores  #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab nele. Também substitui h1 {} e o animate mantive o mesmo, até porque é igual.

Comparei ambos os códigos e não vi diferença que pudesse afetar o funcionamento. Talvez outra pessoa possa encontrar, mas nesse primeiro momento eu não achei nada. Comparei usando o site [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/file-diff)

```css
section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: Gradient 2s ease infinite;
}

h1 {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
font-size: 2em;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Lato';
border: 1px solid #fff;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Código Original</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Se vc passar o `background-size: 400% 400%;` para linha de cima do `background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);` ou seja que o `background-size` vier antes do shorthand `background` a animação falha, pq o `background-size: 400% 400%;` deixa de ser aplicado caso venha antes do `background`

Comment: Verdade. Não tinha me atentado a isso. Eu até cheguei a cogitar, mas não acreditei que isso fosse causar um problema assim. Serve de experiência pra testar todas as alternativas. Obrigado.